# MYSQL - Update an entire Column

Tags: mysql

I wanted to ask if there is a way to update an entire column with the same value.
I want to run '0' down a column or '1'.
I can use a php loop to do it but it will involve multiple DB calls etc.

Hopeing for a SQL statement that can run the same value down an entire mysql column.

cheers

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Something a simple as `UPDATE table1 SET column1=1;` should do it.

Answer (score 11):

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = 0
```

this will set the column value to 0 for all records, if this it want you want.

Comment: You can remove the `WHERE 1`. It's not needed.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to subtract:

```
update table set col=col-1
```

or just update

```
update table set col=0
```

without any where clause